# Correct use of lambda expression with Optional#orElseThrow

Tags: java, functional-interface

Consider the following simple example:

```
Optional.empty().orElseThrow(this::exceptionSupplier);
```

IntelliJ generates a method like the following for the supplier, tough it does not compile!

```
private <X extends Throwable> X exceptionSupplier() {
    return new RuntimeException();
}
```

Incompatible types.
Required: X
Found: java.lang.RuntimeException

If i change the signature to the following it works.

```
private Exception exceptionSupplier() {
    return new RuntimeException();
}
```

Is it correct that the compiler cannot determine the correct type for `X`?

Comment: `X` is determined at the call site. What if the caller asks for an `InterruptedException`?

Comment: Simpler and better to just use a constructor reference here: `Optional.empty().orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)`

Comment: @ernest_k Sure, though this is a simple example and i discovered this problem when refactoring large exception suppliers to a separate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first example were to work, consider the following:

```
Supplier<InterruptedException> s = this::exceptionSupplier;
```

This would then fail with a `ClassCastException` if you called it like so:

```
InterruptedException e = s.get();
```

This is because `X` is determined at the call site. There is an implicit cast inserted by the compiler:

```
InterruptedException e = (InterruptedException) s.get();
```

But, of course, `s` returns you a `RuntimeException`, which can't be cast to `InterruptedException`.

If you want to return a `RuntimeException`, make the return type of the method `RuntimeException`, no type variable required.

Comment: Probably the generated template is a bit confusing.